# Problems reading .bz2 or .tar.bz2 files as hdf5 in R

Tags: linux, r, hdf5, bzip2

I downloaded some files with extension .tar.bz2. I was able to untar these into folders containing .bz2 files. These should unzip as hdf5 files (Metadata said they were hdf5) , but they unzip into files with no extensions I have tried the following but didnt work:

```
untar("File.tar.bz2")

#Read lines of one of the files from the unzipped file
readLines(bzfile("File1.bz2"))
[1] "‰HDF" "\032"

library (rhdf5)
#Explore just as a bzip2 file
bzfile("File1.bz2")
description   "File1.bz2" 
 class        "bzfile" 
 mode         "rb" 
 text         "text" 
 opened       "closed" 
 can read     "yes" 
 can write    "yes"

#Try to read as hdf5 using rhdf5 library 
h5ls(bzfile("File1.bz2"))
Error in h5checktypeOrOpenLoc(). Argument neither of class H5IdComponent  nor a character.
```

Is there some sort of encoding I need to do? What am I missing? What should I do?

Comment: Well, two of those function calls are wrong. `ReadLines` should be `readLines` and `Library` should be `library`.  It would be best to show the error(s) you are receiving as well.

Comment: Hi, Richard. That was typed in error. I just corrected it.